# query returning amount of rows including ones that were deleted,

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

so  I'm trying to get the amount of rows that exist in a mysql table using `JDBC` but using the first column as reference since this is the amount of rows that exist, but this column is  on  `AUTO_INCREMENT`  BUT, lets say   `n  rows` are deleted from table, then some  new ones are `inserted`,  the row number for the new ones will keep count in the same order, naturally, and when  i want to count the number of rows  that the table has, and my  `getTableInfo` method returns the amount of rows  INCLUDING  the ones that were deleted..  how do i solve this ?    can this be done  differently than  this:

```
public int getTableInfo(String tableName, String db, Boolean columnCount,
        Boolean rowCount) {

    TABLE = tableName;

    Connection getTableInfoConn = this.getConnect_to_DB(db);

    try {
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = getTableInfoConn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `" + tableName + "`");

        ResultSet res = prepStatement.executeQuery();

        if ((columnCount == false) && (rowCount == false)
                || (columnCount == null) && (rowCount == false)
                || (columnCount == false) && (rowCount == null)
                || (columnCount == null) && (rowCount == null)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "uno de los booleanos debe ser TRUE", null,
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);

        } else {

            if (columnCount == false && rowCount == true
                    || columnCount == null) {

                while (res.next()) {

                    resultMetaData = res.getInt(1);
                }
            } else if (columnCount == true && rowCount == false
                    || rowCount == null) {

                metaData = res.getMetaData();

                resultMetaData = metaData.getColumnCount();

            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in getTableInfo():" + e);
    }

    return resultMetaData;

}
```

Comment: FYI: If `tableName` comes from the user, this code is subject to SQL Injection.

Comment: yes, thanks, I'm still learning on that but I'll implement it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just count the number of rows in a table you can do it simply with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```

then `res.getInt(1)` should be the number of rows in the table.

If you want to also count the deleted rows, and you have auto-increment on `ID` then you want something like:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable
```

then `res.getInt(1)` should be the number of rows in the table + the deleted rows.

This depends on the correctness of your auto-increment. Some auto-increments will actually skip numbers for the sake of database optimization. This generally isn't the purpose of auto-incrementing, so it's generally not guaranteed by any of them. That being said, if by some configuration you can guarantee it will be right then this will work.

Alternatively you can have a `MyTableDeleted` table. You can have a delete trigger on `MyTable` to populate the row into `MyTableDeleted`. Then getting the number of deleteds is easy.

Comment: this is how I'm  doing  it, but  it returns what I've allready said above.

Comment: @user3363537 I don't see `COUNT(*)` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column is *not* the same thing as the number of rows in the table.

To get the number of rows in a table, you could run a query with an aggregate function in the SELECT list (e.g. **`COUNT(1)`** or **`SUM(1)`**.)

Alternatively, if you want to use an inefficient approach (like retrieving the entire table, fetching each and every row by agonizing row), you could simply initialize a simple counter variable before the loop, and increment the counter variable by 1 for every row fetched.